# Multinode cassandra cluster: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers')

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

For my 6 node cluster, I am unable to `cqlsh <ip>` to the cluster. It gives me :

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.19.2': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.1' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.4.4']",)})

But, I checked `nodetool status`, all my nodes are up and running. Also, I am able to contact the cluster via client.

For the cassandra.yaml on each node, I set the following parameters:

listen_address: node's ip

broadcast_address: node's ip

rpc_address: node's ip

broadcast_address: left blank

seed node: same two ips in each nodes

What seems to be the issue?

**Update:**
I am able to cqlsh from other nodes but not from the first nodes. I can observe that while working on the first node, I somehow messed up with its cqlsh version. Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 0):

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
>   {'192.168.19.2': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.1' is not supported
>   by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.4.4']",)})

You do have different versions of cassandra installed or using the wrong driver. You want to upgrade to your drivers for connecting to your cluster as 3.4 seems to be a 3.10.x cluster while your driver only supports 3.0.x.

Comment: I just found out that accidently messed up with cassandra driver version. How may I restore the original cassandra driver version?

Comment: you can download them here: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/drivers.html